# Read parameter from file on built project Angular

Tags: angular

I have a built project with the default structure:

[image]

I would like to add a new file on that directory containing an URL, so that the built client reads the value on runtime and makes the requests to that url, instead of setting `environment.prod.ts` and then building.

> Why am I trying to do this? If my server url changes, with this solution there is no need
>   to rebuild the project with the new URL value. It would only be neccessary to change the url on that new file.

Is this possible? Didn't find any info about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this way:

- **1.** Create a `config.json` file in Assets folder with the url
- **2.** Create a Service like the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AppConfigService {
  private appConfig;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  loadAppConfig() {
    return this.http
      .get('/assets/config.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
        this.appConfig = data;
      });
  }

  getServerUrl(): string {
    return this.appConfig.url;
  }
}
```

- **3.** In app.module.ts:

Create function:

```
const initializerConfigFn = (appConfig: AppConfigService) => {
  return () => {
    return appConfig.loadAppConfig();
  };
};
```

Add in providers:

```
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: initializerConfigFn,
  multi: true,
  deps: [AppConfigService],
},
```

- **4.** After `ng build --prod`, an Assets file is created with the `config.json` file inside. There is where the url is set. In the code, I'm using `getServerUrl()` for getting that URL.

Here is the [tutorial followed](https://nbe.io/load-a-configuration-at-runtime-with-angular/).

Answer (score 0):

If your application is SSR With Angular Universal or a self-updating PWA this might be a pattern that  works.

But if it's a standard angular project downloaded on the client, I'm not entirely sure your updating of that URL will work properly.

So even though I don't recommend you do this, you could technically add a separate 'script' file next to your node_module folder and add it to your angular.json's 'scripts' array, similarly to this:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
]
```

but of course, don't place your custom script in node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the file in `assets` folder and make sure you read the file (or the content inside the file) using `httpClientModule` instead of importing it .